# using node:crypto.Webcrypto as polyfill will result in JestAssertionErrors being ignored is this a bug?

Tags: jestjs

I created a test that is meant to fail but it always passes because the JestAssertionErrors do not cause the tests to fail.

code under test, uses browser crypto api

```
async function sum(a, b) {
  let passKey = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
      name: 'AES-GCM',
      length: 256,
    },
    true,
    ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
  );
  return a + b;
}
```

when this polyfill is used the assertions are ignored (test doesn't failed)

```
const crypto = require('node:crypto');
Object.defineProperty(global.self, "crypto", {
  value: {
    subtle: crypto.webcrypto.subtle,
  },
});

test('sum adds 1 + 2 to equal 5 should fail', () => {
  sum(1, 2).then((result) => {
    expect(result).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

When this polyfill is used the assertions aren't ignored and tests fail as expected

```
// const Crypto = require('@peculiar/webcrypto').Crypto;
const cryptoModule = new Crypto();
Object.defineProperty(global, 'crypto', {
  value: cryptoModule
});

test('sum adds 1 + 2 to equal 5 should fail', () => {
  sum(1, 2).then((result) => {
    expect(result).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

minimal example in this repo: https://github.com/ta32/issues/tree/master/jest_test

The tests passes: [image]

but there are actually assertions:
[image]

Is this a bug in the jest framework?
Even if I have done something wrong, its kind of bad for the test framework to continue like this, but I guess this is the nature of scripting languages like JS.

Comment: What does node:crypto have to do with it? Your assertion is reached _after_ the test finishes, read https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous. And note the [mre] must be **in the question**.

Comment: If you want to test asynchronous code, your test case has to return a promise. Yours doesn't return anything and the assertion fails ling after the testcase had already finished successfully

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I guess using the peculiar/webcrypto polyfill changed the timing on my computer so the assertion was triggered before the test returned on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the test wasn't returning the promise to the jest framework

```
test('sum adds 1 + 2 to equal 5 should fail', () => {
  return sum(1, 2).then((result) => {
    expect(result).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

The @peculiar/webcrypto polyfill probably just changed the timing so the assertion was thrown while the test was running

https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Js is single threaded so if you are using promises they must always be returned.

Comment: Your code doesn't work either, because the testcase doesn't return a promise...

Comment: sorry edited that was a typo copied from a diff